# UrbanAirship: PHP library push notification to named user

Tags: php, urbanairship.com

I see that API v.3 allow to specify "named_user" as Audience for the push notification ([official docs](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#audience-selectors)), but the official PHP library (v.1.3) doesn't support it or I can't find how to do it (in the docs and in the code).

Can anybody help with it?

Comment: IMHO People who vote down without a comment are useless for Stack Overflow community due to they show only personal opinion without suggestion how to make it better for the community.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like UrbanAirship didn't find a time during +1 year to implement this important feature or merge the fix proposed by community from GitHub.

Jonbest implemented a [fix](https://github.com/urbanairship/php-library2/pull/26).

If you use composer you can link the fixed version instead of official from UrbanAirship. You need to make the following changes in the composer.json:

1. Add new section

   ```
   "repositories": [
       {
       "type": "git",
       "url": "https://github.com/jonbest/php-library2"
       }
   ],
   ```
2. Change line in the require section

   ```
   "require":{
       ...
       "urbanairship/urbanairship": "dev-patch-1",
       ...
   }
   ```